# How Can I Make X Axis and Y Axis Exchange and use multiple X Axes in ZedGraph Controls

Tags: zedgraph

I want to draw a graph with multiple vertical curves, each curve corresponds to a horizontal Axis and all these curves share a horizonal vertical Axis. Two approaches may be possible:
1. Make X Axis vertical and make Y Axis horizontal, and then use multiple Y Axes, but how to make X Axis and Y Axis exchange?
2. Use multiple X Axes, but it seems that the ZedGraph only support not more than 2 X Axes. If I want to draw more than two curves, what should I do then?